# How to build "dummy columns" for UNION?

Tags: sql

from what I understand "each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order." Well what if the first SELECT has more columns than the 2nd one can generate. Here's what I mean: let's say I want to

```
SELECT "City", "Country", "Continent" from table1  
UNION  
SELECT "City", "Country" from table2
```

...let's say table 2 does not contain a column called "Continent" but for my needs it's fine for the records that come from table2 to have a blank or NULL in that column. I am using dashDB.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can always add "virtual" columns:

```
SELECT "City", "Country", "Continent" from table1  
UNION  
SELECT "City", "Country", NULL AS "Continent" from table2
```

Comment: yes sir! THAT's what I was looking for ! THANK YOU @Tim Schmelter

Comment: unfortunate that there's no way for this to be understood implicitly

Comment: What would you use if the "Continent" column in table1 is integer type?

Answer (score 10):

Hi,
 You can use,

```
SELECT "City", "Country", "Continent" from table1  
UNION  
SELECT "City", "Country", ' ' as "Continent"  from table2
```

or

```
 SELECT "City", "Country", "Continent" from table1  
    UNION  
 SELECT "City", "Country", NULL as "Continent"  from table2
```

It considers "Continent" as null in table2